# Bootstrap table-condensed only for xs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use table-condensed, but only when xs. I tried this, but no luck.

```
<table class="hidden-xs table">
<table class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg table table-condensed">
```

It hides the whole table for the 2nd one. Is there a way I can get condensed only in xs without repeating the entire table structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table-condensed` doesn't do anything other than change the padding. Instead of duplicating the table, it would be better to add your own CSS class that works at the smallest (xs) breakpoint..

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .table-condensed-xs > thead > tr > th,
  .table-condensed-xs > tbody > tr > th,
  .table-condensed-xs > tfoot > tr > th,
  .table-condensed-xs > thead > tr > td,
  .table-condensed-xs > tbody > tr > td,
  .table-condensed-xs > tfoot > tr > td {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/5ndhSVOeeh

Or, you could override the existing `table-condensed` class like this..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .table-condensed > thead > tr > th,
  .table-condensed > tbody > tr > th,
  .table-condensed > tfoot > tr > th,
  .table-condensed > thead > tr > td,
  .table-condensed > tbody > tr > td,
  .table-condensed > tfoot > tr > td {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer **No**. Using native bootstrap you cannot manipulate other classes based on `hidden-*` tags.

If you want `table-condensed` on `xs` only, you will need to repeat that code with `visible-xs-block`, marking unwanted code with `hidden-xs`.

You could write custom CSS, or do this with jQuery, you grab `$('table.visible-xs-block')` and add class `table-condensed` to it : `$('table.visible-xs-block').addClass('table-condensed')`. This should work, mark-up is from my memory, so tweak it to your needs.